# SearchView Menu Icon disappearing for CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, searchview, android-coordinatorlayout

I am facing strange problem with `SearchView` in toolbar.
I want to use `CoordinatorLayout` for my layout, so recently I have changed my root layout from `LinearLayout` to `CoordinatorLayout`. Everything is fine except the behavior of `SearchView` I am using is in `Toolbar` is strange after clicking search icon.

With LinearLayout

[image]

With CoordinatorLayout

[image]

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/white"
>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_for_home_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/appcolor">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_progress_bar"
            style="@style/AppTheme"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/white"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
            android:visibility="gone" />


     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout_for_home_ativity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/appcolor"
        app:tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/lightblue" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager_for_home_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingbutton_for_home_fragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add_white_24dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/appcolor"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_behavior="com.ficean.android.ficean.ScrollingFABBehavior" />

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the above code if I change Coordinator layout to LinearLayout SearchView is showing up fine. If I use Coordinator layout searchicon and edittext are disappearing. But keypad is getting opened and I can still search. Problem is search icon and edit text is not showing up.

Menu Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="Search"
        android:id="@+id/search_on_activity_toolbar"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

        />
</menu>
```

Comment: It's working with these codes : http://paste.ofcode.org/UBV6p9jbBD2t9rmbh7sMbz - Image : http://imgur.com/mw44DGu Check your colors which you set them for `Toolbar` background `for example`... I've deleted them and it does show up!